# Setting browser autofill values in dropdown JavaScript angular

Tags: javascript, html, autofill

I have an address form having Name, Address, Country and state, where country and state is dropdown.

Now User can autofill the form, but it does not work for dropdown. Is there any way that I can listen autofill event and then get the complete object of browser autofill values and then manually set the dropdown values?

I am not able to find anything related to this, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for a browser to autofill a select, input and textarea elements there needs to be:

- a `name` and `id` attribute on the element
- be a child of a form element
- the form needs a submit button

You can find all these requirements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

You would then need to add the `autocomplete="country"` attribute for the country element and `autocomplete="address-level1"` for the state element.

Example:

```
<form>
  <select id="country" name="country" autocomplete="country">
      <option>Choose your country</option>
  </select>
  <select id="state" name="state" autocomplete="address-level1">
      <option>Choose your state</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```